# Two versions of Isotope in Wordpress installation

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I use a Wordpress theme that loads Isotope v1.5.25 jQuery plugin for theme functions. But I also use a wordpress plugin that loads Isotope v2.0.0. These two jQuery versions conflict and results in bugs etc. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to disable one of the two scripts, I will say, if the theme wont throw any bugs by using the version 2 of the plugin, then you will need to disable the older version by commenting the include of the theme version of Isotope.

This can be done from two ways:

- If the theme uses wp_register_script/wp_enqueue_script, then you will have to search for this script enqueue line and comment it, or remove it from any script that uses it as a requirement
- If no wp_register_script/enqueue is used, then most likely the file is loaded in the header.php of your theme, go there and remove the  tag that includes the file.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, I removed the older version the theme is using but now a lot of functionality is missing on the site..Any other ideas?

Comment: This is more likely because it looks like Isotope 2.x is not backward compatible. You have a big issue here. I will tell you to reconsider using other plugin that uses the same version of Isotope or another library.